# Webapp2: Form.Validate() failing in User Login Handler

Tags: python, forms, validation, webapp2, wtforms

I am building a User Signup and Login module. I am passing email and password in the Login form. I am using WTForms for Forms. I am following this tutorial.

[User Accounts with Webapp2 + Google App Engine](http://gosurob.com/post/20024043690/gaewebapp2accounts)

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    email = TextField('Email',
        [validators.Required(), validators.Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password',
        [validators.Required()])

class LoginHandler(UserAwareHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render_response("login.html", form=LoginForm())

    def post(self):
        form = LoginForm(self.request.POST)
        error = None

        if form.validate():  # This is where it fails
            try:
                self.auth.get_user_by_password(
                    "auth:"+form.email.data,
                    form.password.data)
                return self.redirect_to('Profile', user_id=form.email.data)
            except (auth.InvalidAuthIdError, auth.InvalidPasswordError):
                error = "Invalid Email / Password"
        print "It's not working!!"
        self.render_response("login.html",
                    form=form,
                    error=error
```

The form above doesn't validate if I enter a username - "xxx@gmail.com", and a Password "abcdef".

I am new to Webapp2 and I'm at a loss understanding the error here. Also, is there any way to know why your form is not getting validated?

The output is 
xxx@gmail.com
abcdef
It's not working!!

```
INFO     2014-04-05 11:07:44,359 module.py:612] default: "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 1228
INFO     2014-04-05 11:07:44,414 module.py:612] default: "GET /static/css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-04-05 11:07:44,414 module.py:612] default: "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Can someone please help. I am stuck with this for long. Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you provide the full trace error?

Comment: @user3269848 were you able to solve this? You need to tell us what **not working** means. The best would be in the form of "I expect <this> but when I run it I see <this>" otherwise I have to add you to the close queue. Your stack indicates a successful post returning a 200 response code.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't solve the error and left webapp2 to migrate to web2py. 

In the above question, my form was not validating even though I entered perfectly valid inputs (an email and a password).

I expected - Either user to be logged in or "Invalid Email / Password" error.

Instead I got - "It's not working"